# Last.fm or Spotify API

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, codeigniter, embedded-resource

I was hoping someone could offer me advice, Im looking to build a website, and was hoping that I could inergrate my last.fm radio station or my spotify account into it so the users can listen to what I am. I know there are API's for each but do any of them support listening to music, nothing seems conclusive in there documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the best your going to get without going around their systems in some very clever way.

Also the licensing from both likely prevents you from doing what your suggesting, your best bet is with last.fm, Spotify has an incredibly restrictive api.

Sorry.

Comment: .. Nor basically anywhere else either Zack ;) At least, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could direct users to the Spotify listening URLs. This requires them to have Spotify, but it means they can listen to your playlist/stuff.